# Image Button not removing selected item from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclick, imagebutton

I created a calorie app for my class project. I'm trying to remove an item from a listview. The way I have it setup is I created an imagebutton in the listivew .xml. For some reason when the user clicks on the imagebutton "fooddelete" it doesnt do anything.

Thank you so much, I'm new to android studio this my first app and working with fragments.

```
public class FragmentHome extends   Fragment  implements 

View.OnClickListener {


public TextView caloriesTotal
private TextView caloriesRemain;

private ListView listView;
private LinearLayout mLayout;

private Animation anim;
ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
ImageButton ResetEntry;
ImageButton FoodDelete;
Context context;

int goalCalories;
int totalCalorie;
int tdee;
Button mButton;
String formattedCalories ;
String formattedRemain ;
//Database
private DatabaseHandler dba;
private ArrayList<Food> dbFoods = new ArrayList<>();
private CustomListViewAdapter foodAdapter;
private Food myFood ;
//fragment
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
public FragmentHome() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, 
    false);
caloriesTotal = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calorie_amount);

caloriesRemain = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.calorieRemain);

listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListId);



SharedPreferences prefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

SharedPreferences userInfo =getContext().getSharedPreferences("userInfo",0);
tdee= userInfo.getInt("tdee",0);
caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);
AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);

AddEntrybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(4);
        }
    });




  ResetEntry = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.ResetEntry);
 ResetEntry.setOnClickListener(this);


  ** Get Error Here  **
     //  void   
    // android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener
   // (android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
   **   **

   FoodDelete = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fooddelete);

    FoodDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

refreshData();

anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
listView.startAnimation(anim);

return myView;
}


public void reset ()  {

dbFoods.clear();

dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();
//Loop
for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){

String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

myFood= new Food();
myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
myFood.setFoodName(name);
myFood.setCalories(cal);
myFood.setRecordDate(date);

dbFoods.clear();

dbFoods.remove(myFood);
foodsFromDB.remove(myFood);
dba.deleteFood(foodId);
 }
dba.close();
//setting food Adapter:
foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
listView.startAnimation(anim);
}

public void refreshData (){

dbFoods.clear();
dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();

totalCalorie = dba.totalCalories();

formattedCalories = Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie);
formattedRemain = Utils.formatNumber(  tdee-totalCalorie);

 //setting the editTexts:
 caloriesTotal.setText("Total Calories: " + formattedCalories);

 caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);

 SharedPreferences prefs = 
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

 SharedPreferences userInfo = 
 getContext().getSharedPreferences("userInfo",0);
int tdee= userInfo.getInt("tdee",0);
caloriesRemain.setText(" "+tdee);

    //Loop
for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){

String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

myFood= new Food();
myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
myFood.setFoodName(name);
myFood.setCalories(cal);
myFood.setRecordDate(date);
dbFoods.add(myFood);
}
dba.close();
//setting food Adapter:
foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
listView.startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

String username1 = username.getString("Username");

TextView userMain= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);

userMain.setText(username1);

SharedPreferences userInfo = 
getContext().getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
int tdee= userInfo.getInt("tdee",0);
caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
}

 @Override
 public void onDetach() {
 super.onDetach();

 startActivity( new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.AddItems:

            AddEntry addEntry = new AddEntry();

            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder, addEntry)

                    .commit();
                     break;

    case R.id.ResetEntry:


            reset();
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), 
            R.anim.fading);
            listView.startAnimation(anim);
            break;



    case  R.id.fooddelete:

            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + dbFoods);

            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             foodAdapter.remove(dbFoods.get(dbFoods.indexOf(myFood)));
                    foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            break;
          }


       }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly so that we can understand it easily.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by formatting code properly.

Comment: Look at the indents of your pasted code. Does it look correct?

Comment: will Fix it Sorry about that

Comment: I updated where I'm getting the error

Comment: Can you show us the "fragment_home.xml" file as well?